# Linq: group by + count for one column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this query in SQL

```
     select FileName, UploadDate, Status 
     from MyTable group by FileName, UploadDate, Status
```

this give me the correct output

```
FileName    UploadDate              Status
fuel 1.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:04.857 1
fuel 1.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:04.857 4
fuel 2.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:17.193 4
```

I can translate this query to LINQ

```
context.MyTable
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileName, x.UploadDate, x.Status })
                .Select(x => new { x.Key.FileName, x.Key.UploadDate, x.Key.Status });
```

Now i wanna the same query but an additional column with the count of the 'Status' column

i Accomplish this in SQL with this query

```
select FileName, UploadDate, Status, count(Status) as 'StatusCount' 
from MyTable group by FileName, UploadDate, Status
```

This give me the correct output

```
FileName    UploadDate             Status   StatusCount
fuel 1.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:04.857 1       19
fuel 1.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:04.857 4       1
fuel 2.xls  2020-04-10 17:43:17.193 4       20
```

How to translate this additional "column count" into LINQ?i've tried several times different solutions but without success. Can someone help me please?

Comment: `count(status)` could also be `count(*)`. `status` has no more meaning for count here than any of the other fields in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean count:

```
context.MyTable
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileName, x.UploadDate, x.Status })
   .Select(x => new { x.Key.FileName, x.Key.UploadDate, x.Key.Status,
                      Count = x.Count() });
```

If you actually meant Sum:

```
context.MyTable
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileName, x.UploadDate, x.Status })
   .Select(x => new { x.Key.FileName, x.Key.UploadDate, x.Key.Status,
                      Sum = x.Sum(e => e.Status) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the `Count` method on each `IGrouping<>` object in the `Select` method :

```
context.MyTable
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileName, x.UploadDate, x.Status })
            .Select(x => new 
                           { 
                             FileName = x.Key.FileName, 
                             UploadDate = x.Key.UploadDate, 
                             Status = x.Key.Status,
                             Count = x.Count()
                    });
```